# Why is my PATCH request empty in an ASP.NET Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, json-patch

I have the following ASP.net Core Controller:

```
[ApiVersion(ApiConstants.Versions.V1)]
[Route(RouteConstants.ApiControllerPrefix + "/tenants/" + RouteConstants.TenantIdRegex + "/entities")]
public class EntityController
{
    [HttpPatch]
    [SwaggerOperation(OperationId = nameof(PatchEntity))]
    [Route("{controlId:guid}", Name = nameof(PatchEntity))]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent, "Result of the patch")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    [Consumes(MediaTypes.Application.JsonPatch)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PatchEntity(string tenantId, Guid entityId, JsonPatchDocument<EntityModel> entityPatches)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The controller allows me to patch an existing entity. Here is the model:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class EntityModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isAuthorized")]
    public bool IsAuthorized { get; set; }
}
```

For my test, I am using `postman` to send a patch on an entity. I selected the verb `PATCH` targeted to this URL:

```
http://localhost:5012/api/v1/tenants/tenant-id/entities/01111111-0D1C-44D6-ABC4-2C9961F94905
```

In the headers, I added the `Content-Type` entry and set it to `application/json-patch+json`.

Here is the body of the request:

```
[
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/isAuthorized", "value": "false" }
]
```

I started the application and set a breakpoint on the controller. The breakpoint is hit, with the proper tenant ID and entity ID. However, the `entityPatches` does not have any operations:

```
entityPatches.Operations.Count = 0
```

Consequently, the property `IsAuthorized` of the targeted `EntityModel` can't be updated. I would have expected the `Operations` property to have one `replace` operation, as defined in the HTTP request.

**Question**

Why is the `Operations` property of the `JsonPatchDocument` class missing the patch operations defined in the body of the HTTP request?

Comment: Have you tried adding `[FromBody]` to the `entityPatches` parameter?

Comment: @DavidG Oohh no *sigh* You are correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the [`FromBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) attribute on the `entityPatches` parameter, for example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PatchEntity(
    string tenantId, 
    Guid entityId, 
    [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<EntityModel> entityPatches)
  //^^^^^^^^^^ Add this
{
    //snip
}
```

Comment: I just saw that I could use [ApiControllerAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and ControllerBase with ASP.Net Core 2.1 and not have the need to put FromBody anymore :)